# bash call is creating a new process.I want to the next command in same process

Tags: bash

I am logging into a remote server using SSH client. I have written a script that will execute two commands on the server.But, as the first command executes a bash script that calls "bash" command at the end. This results in execution of only one command not the other.

I cannot edit the first script to comment or remove the bash call.

i have written following script:

abc.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
command1="sudo -u user_abc -H /abc/xyz/start_shell.sh"
command2=".try1.sh"
$command1 && $command2
```

Only command 1 is getting executed not the second as the "bash" call is creating a new process the second command is not executing.

Comment: This executes `$command1` first and upon its return, `$command2` is executed only if `$command1` returned successfully (return code `0`). If this is not what you need, explain with more details what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1

Since you can execute `start_shell.sh` you must have read permissions. Therefore, you could copy the script, modify it such that it doesn't call bash anymore, and execute the modified version.

I think this would be the best solution. If you really really really have to use `start_shell.sh` as is, then you could try one of the following solutions.

#### Solution 2

Try closing stdin using `<&-`. An interactive bash session will exit immediately if there is no stdin.

```
sudo -u user_abc -H /abc/xyz/start_shell.sh <&-; ./try1.sh
```

#### Solution 3

Change the order if both commands are independent.

```
./try1.sh; sudo -u user_abc -H /abc/xyz/start_shell.sh
```